# PCA- Principal Component Analysis in Matlab , code

Tags: matlab, pca

I would ike to perform PCA of my feature selection in Matlab. As I understand in Matlab is already pre compiled function 
[pc, zscores, pcvars] = princomp(yeastvalues)

Is that true or I need something else??

Comment: Princomp is a function of the "statistics toolbox" and not pure matlab if that was your question.

Comment: What are you asking? Have you googled the `princomp` function? As it stands you are asking nothing

Comment: In latest version of MATLAB, you should use `pca`

Comment: I have 9x66 dataset. I have extracted  9 parameters (features) that should describe the users run while they are performing some task on a mobile robotics platforms. I would like to use SVM to classify the user run. So, would like to use PCA to see which features are most important for the classification. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions of MATLAB, the best function to use is `pca`. This is intended to gradually replace the old function `princomp`, although `princomp` is still supported for backward compatibility, and I would think is likely to remain so for at least a few versions.

Both `pca` and `princomp` are part of Statistics Toolbox. You can check whether you have Statistics Toolbox installed by typing the command `ver`, which will list all your installed products.

The outputs of either command are typically labelled `[coeffs, scores, latent]`. The first is the coefficients of the principal components. The second is the principal component scores (which are not at all the same thing as z-scores). The third is the principal component variances. Given your variable naming `[pc, zscores, pcvars]`, I'm not sure what you're expecting to get, but that is what you will get.

Comment: Yes, I have the statistics Toolbox. So I can use princomp or pca. So what should I do with the dataset before use princomp or pca?

Comment: I have no idea what you should do with your data, before or after you apply PCA - that completely depends on what your data is like, and what questions you want to answer. If your data is all numeric then you can just put it straight into PCA, but depending on your application you might want to centre it, perhaps scale it, or apply some other transform to it. If it's not numeric, or if it contains missing data, you would need to alter it in some other way. Noone can answer that without knowing your application and the nature of your data.

Comment: My Application is in assistive robotics. So,Im extracting some parameters from my sensor data that I think are relevant to classify the users run while they are performing some task.
I get the movement data from the sensor package deployed on the wheelchair. Im classify certain action like turning 180 degree, and Im giving him a mark (from 1 to 4)

So from the sensor package and the software I had extracted parameters like velocity, distance, time, standard deviation of the velocity etc. that are relevant for the classification of the users run. So my data are all numbers. Hope is clear now.

Comment: drtoolbox  is useful for dimensionality reduction operations. http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/Matlab_Toolbox_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.html